# Cocoa: custom NSCell not respond double click action

Tags: nstableview, double-click, nscell, nstableviewcell

I focus on a cocoa app supported on 10.6, and I use cell-based `NSTableView`.

I custom the `NSCell` so that it can display image and text.
The Problem here is : when I set the `doubleClickAction` to the tableview, it did not respond.

I have already found it due to the custom cell. I guess the cell stops the responding chain, but I don't know how to fix it. I search the document, and I've no idea which method to be overridden.

Please give some guides and Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this question as I did, the solution in my case was a missed call to:

```
[self.tableView setTarget:self]; //This was missed
[self.tableView setDoubleClickAction:@selector(doubleClick:)];
```